# SlapshScreen Monogame Wp8

Tags: xna, xna-4.0, monogame

I try to making a splash screen 
all i want is wait at splash screen for 1 sec then automatically load to play screen .

I try to use Thread.Sleep() but it's not work .

Any idea,Plsssssssss .
THANKS YOU :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try something like this

```cs
timer = 10000f; // 10 seconds
```

Then in the update method:

```cs
timer -= gameTime.ElapsedGameTime.TotalMilliseconds;

if (timer <= 0.0f)
{
    // trigger whatever happens when the timer expires.
}
```

Comment: I would use TotalSeconds, count upwards and have the if check with a const or something similar. otherwise I agree with the general solution :)

Answer (score 1):

*Davor*'s solution is fine, but I suggest you to use `TimeSpan` if you have to handle with time:

```cs
TimeSpan timer = new TimeSpan(0, 0, 1); //1 second
```

Then in the `Update` method:

```cs
if (timer > TimeSpan.Zero)
  timer -= gameTime.ElapsedGameTime;

if (timer < TimeSpan.Zero)
{
  timer = TimeSpan.Zero;
  //load your play screen
}
```

`timer = TimeSpan.Zero` ensures that you load your play screen only once.

Comment: What's the advantage of using a timespan in this case?

Comment: I always prefer using TimeSpan when handling with time, so if you need to show it on screen with different formats you can use ToString method

Comment: Advantage in this case is mostly that you keep your code cleaner and simpler by not throwing around big numbers and what pinckerman states above.

Comment: I agree with the "big numbers" issue, I usually measure things in seconds instead of milliseconds so that helps. What looks cleaner seems to be personal preference I guess.